# Incorrect string being output into DF Pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a loop which scans a website for a particular element and then scrapes it and places it within a list and then this gets put into a string variable.

Postalcode3 outputs fine to the DF and this in turn outputs correctly to the csv, however, postalcode4 does not output anything and those cells are simply skipped from the csv

Here is the loop function -

```
for i in range (30):
    page = requests.get('https://www.example.com'+ df.loc[i,'ga:pagePath'])
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    postalcode2 = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]/text()')
    postalcode = tree.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()')
    if not postalcode2 and not postalcode:
        print(postalcode,postalcode2)
    elif not postalcode2:
        postalcode4 = postalcode[0]
        # postalcode4 = postalcode4.replace(' ','')
        df.loc[i,'postcode'] = postalcode4
    elif not postalcode:
        postalcode3 = postalcode2[0]
        if 'Â' not in postalcode3:
            postalcode3 = postalcode3.replace('\\xa0','')
            postalcode3 = postalcode3.replace(' ','')
        else:
            postalcode3 = postalcode3.replace('\\xa0Â','')
            postalcode3 = postalcode3.replace(' ','')
    df.loc[i,'postcode'] = postalcode3
```

I have debugged it and can see that the string output by postalcode4 is correct and in the same format as postalcode3.

Postalcode3 has a load of character removal elements placed in as that particular web element comes full of useless characters.

I'm not entirely sure what's gone wrong.

This is how I read in the DF and insert the new column which will be written into by the loop function.

```
files = 'example.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(files, index_col=0)
df.insert(5,'postcode','')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you aren't handling the web output correctly.

The `content` attribute of a `requests.get` response is a bytestring, but HTML content is text. If you don't decode the bytestring before you create the HTML then you may well find extraneous characters due to the encoding appear in your text. The correct way to handle these is not, however, to continue with a bytestring, but instead to convert the incoming bytestring to text by decoding it before calling `html.fromstring`.

You should really find the correct encoding using the `Content-Encoding` header, if it's present. As an experiment you  might try replacing

```
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

with

```
tree = html.fromstring(page.content.decode('utf-8')`
```

since many web sites will use UTF8 encoding. You may find that the responses then appear to make more sense, and that you don't need to strip so much "extraneous" stuff out.